# How is this filter done?

Tags: post-processing, photo-editing, effect, instagram

I was hoping someone could help me figure out what app or filter is used on these pictures? I've been trying to figure it out for days by looking into stereoscopic or vintage looks but I haven't had great luck. It has this RGB look without actually moving into 3D. I'm pretty sure it's an app, but which one?
Thanks!
[image] 
[image]

Comment: [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/15871)

Comment: @R.A., do you mean the red/blue colored bands that show on some edges? Or the general color speckling all over the shot?

Comment: What I see here is just really bad image quality. You will see those "features" if you get one of these cheap plastic film cameras and buy the cheapest color films.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the [Gudak Cam](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gudak-cam/id1237692856?mt=8) app. The idol in your examples, in his recent pictures the effect looks quite strong compared to other idols' pictures, so he might be using something else, but most of the IG pictures with chromatic aberration lately are done with Gudak Cam.

Answer (score 3):

The "effect" I can see in the pictures (that "stereoscopic or vintage look") is called [chromatic aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration).
It's an unwanted lens property. Usually cheaper lenses in specific conditions (like with aperture wide open) have it quite pronounced.

If you are interested in creating such an effect, you can actually use a tool for fixing this defect in the reverse mode. The tool must offer manual setting, of course. Just move sliders to create the level of chromatic aberration as needed.

The [Fix CA](http://kcd.sourceforge.net/fix-ca.php) plugin for Gimp is capable of doing that.

Comment: I think this is rather _color noise_, produced by high ISO (and jerked-up saturation). _Chromatic aberration_ should produce green and purple lines around edges.

Comment: Look at the OP's pictures. The colour fringes (lines) are present there. They can also be blue/red (not only green/purple).

Comment: They are, but I think that is not what he meant. We should get that info from him.

Answer (score 0):

The effect created happens when lights of different colors have an offset between them. As other answers mentioned, this can happen with low-quality lenses. This is because the refraction angle depends on the wavelength of the light.

You can also simulate this effect. In Photoshop, you can do this by shifting every channel (red, green and blue):

1. Create 2 copies of the layer (right-click on the layer in the Layers window and click duplicate, then repeat). Call the two coppies "red" and "blue".
2. Double click on the "blue" layer's icon (on the left of it's name). The layer style options will open.
3. In the Blending options tab, find the "Advanced blending" box. There, disable every channel except B (blue). Now, only the blue channel will be overwritten by this layer, and the other channels will remain in the values of the layers underneath.
4. Click OK. You will not notice any changes, because the blue channel hasn't moved. However, now you have the ability to displace the blue channel individually.
5. Select the layer called "blue" and move or distort it somehow. For example, move it 3 pixels right.
6. Repeat steps 2 to 5 for the layer called "red", except that:

   1. Only leave the R (red) channel on
   2. Move the layer in a different way than the blue layer. For example, move it 3 pixels left.

This works because the Red and Blue layers now override the Red and Blue channels while leaving the Green channel how it was set by the base layer. This simulates the channel shifting occuring in bad lenses due to different refraction angles.